# STM32 beginner board

Tags: stm32, board, development-tools

I want to buy an STM32 development board, and I was thinking to try one of these really cheap ones on eBay (from China). My choice is the following:

*[Core407V STM32F407VET6 STM32 Cortex-M4 Development Board Mainboard Module Kit](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Core407V-STM32F407VET6-STM32-Cortex-M4-Development-Board-Mainboard-Module-Kit-/142124645773?epid=6003301238&hash=item211749fd8d:g:58cAAOSw4shX4nZU)* along with the programmer for the board: 
*[Mini ST-Link V2 Stlink Emulator Downloader Programming STM8 STM32 Shell Metal](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-ST-Link-V2-Stlink-Emulator-Downloader-Programming-STM8-STM32-Shell-Metal-/172551806965?hash=item282ce39ff5:g:pyIAAOSwax5Ys4xy)*.

Will I be able to use the Coocox IDE or the GNU ARM Eclipse in order to be able to program it? Will I also be able to use the various libraries from ST Microelectronics? For me it's just a hobby and that's the main reason why I don't want to spent too much money on it.

Comment: An Official STM32 dev board with on-board programmer can be bought under 11$ on [Farnell](http://www.newark.com/search?st=Nucleo). This board can be used to program other custom STM32 boards later. Buying an undocumented, fakish chinesee board for more would be a bad decision.

Comment: The official STM boards are also included in the Cube software so you can configure them and generate driver code automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will i be able to use the Coocox IDE or the GNU ARM Eclipse in order to be able to program it?

it can be programmed with coide 1.x at least. I would recommend against 2.x as it is  a mess.

> Will i also be able to use the various libraries from ST Microelectronics?

it can be programmed with the standard peripheral library, and others from ST.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to.

I am using a variant of that board (ZET variant) and a clone STLink programmer (not the same one as in the link) and I am programming it using System Workbench. I would think CooCox should work as well.